# finish() leaking memory but onBackPressed() is not

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory, activity-finish, onbackpressed

I was attempting to track down memory leaks today in an application which has been hitting out-of-memory on some of the older devices. One of the leaks I found really threw me. I solved the leak but I was wondering if anybody had any insight into why the fix works at all.

The activity (let's call it activity B) that is leaking has an icon that is an 'x' for the user to exit that activity. When the x is pressed, it called finish() and then returns to activity A. The code for this click event is below:

```
    View ivExit = findViewById(R.id.imageview_exit);
    ivExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isFinishing()) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

The result is that it would work as expected but was leaking memory. However, with one simple change I was able to run the same exact test without any leak. All I had to do was change finish() to onBackPressed() and it no longer leaked. This is very strange to me because I was under the impression that onBackPressed() and finish() are *essentially* the same thing, and yet one of them leaks memory and the other does not. Does anybody know why this would be the case?

Comment: `onBackPressed()` handles some use-case behind the scene but later on it will also call the `finish()` implicitly.

Comment: What is the OS version on that device? Is that is AppCompatActivity?

Comment: The device is a Nexus 5X running Android 6.0.1. And yes, the activity extends AppCompatActivity @j2ko

Comment: It's interesting that you asked @j2ko because when I tested on a different device it didn't occur. Which is extra interesting so this very odd discrepancy only occurs on Nexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in [FragmentedActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/bfc8e01b7b0d5ea70ce89d0409b72b7f7d540f43/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#163) (that is the parent of [AppCompatActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F)) has following code in `onBackPressed`:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

And it hasn't any specific implementation for`finish()`. 
So looks like this `popBackStackImmediate` somehow affects your flow.
I found `OS 5.1.1` [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#501) :

```
 @Override
 public boolean popBackStackImmediate() {
     checkStateLoss();
     executePendingTransactions();
     return popBackStackState(mActivity.mHandler, null, -1, 0);
 }
```

`executePendingTransactions()` could be the reason why behavior is different between `onBackPressed()` and `finish()` calls.

Comment: That is definitely helpful! I'm so curious why it occurs on Nexus and not other devices. I'll mark this as correct but I am definitely curious still.